# Inspect the Eigen matrix value in visual studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, matrix, debuggervisualizer, eigen3

I'm currently using Visual Studio 2012. I knew that in order to visualize the matrix entries from the Eigen3 library I have to do something as described [here](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Developer%27s_Corner#Debugging_tips). However when I tried the both methods described there and it is still not possible to show the matrix entries when I am debugging in Visual Studio. Does anyone have the same problem and how did you solve it? Thanks!